# hibernate lazy true error

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

I am getting an error when trying to place lazy true to the following propety:

```
 <many-to-one name="ProductCategory" class="com.BiddingSystem.Models.Category" fetch="join" lazy="true">
            <column name="PRODUCTCATEGORY" />
        </many-to-one>
```

Stack Trace:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Attribute "lazy" with value "true" must have a value from the list "false proxy no-proxy ".
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.validateDTDattribute(XMLDTDValidator.java:1414)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.addDTDDefaultAttrsAndValidate(XMLDTDValidator.java:1333)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1940)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:764)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:400)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2755)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
        at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
        at org.hibernate.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:75)
```

Answer (score 5):

lazy="true" is  not allowed in many-to-one mapping. You should user false/proxy/no-proxy.
Thanks.

Comment: but among the three false/proxy/no-proxy which one should i use if i dont want the category object to load

Comment: @Noor, if you feel the answer was useful, please upvote it :-)

Answer (score 5):

From Hibernate 3.1+ lazy="true" was removed from the DTD (which is what is causing your error).
you should use lazy="no-proxy" instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
Attribute "lazy" with value "true" must have a value from the list "false proxy no-proxy ".
```

It should have one of the values inside the list:

```
false, proxy, no-proxy
```

Your answer is already in your stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Actually if you use lazy="no-proxy", you will need to instrument your code. For default lazy loading, you should use "proxy".

Also note that lazy="true/false/extra" is valid for Collection associations.